# How to give links to the texts inside textillate

Tags: jquery, css

i am using a plugin http://textillate.js.org.
My code is,

```
<h1 class="tlt" id="" style="color:#fff;"">   
    <ul class="texts">

        <li>BIG BREAKING</li>
        <li>SAI abc</li>
        <li>SAI xyz</li>
    </ul>
    </h1>
<script>
$('.tlt').textillate({
              selector: '.texts',
              loop: true,
              autoStart: true,
              out: {
              effect: 'fadeOut'

                   }
             });
</script>
```

All things are working perfect like text animations. But i want to give some links to the texts like

```
<li><a href="abc.com">some text</a></li>
<li><a href="xyz.com">another texts</a></li>
```

so that i can navigate to the respective link when i click on the text.

Comment: I'd imagine the plugin is manipulating text based on the item's text or html content. Being that your `<a>` has neither, your fix may be as simple as this: `<li><a href="xyz.com">xyz.com</a></li>`. This being said, i'm not going to put this as an answer as I'm not familiar with this plugin, and it's more of a guess than anything.

Comment: Sorry. i missed out the inside texts. but there should be no confusion. Obviously there is some texts inside the anchor tag.

Comment: I would edit your original post to include this. It isn't "obvious" that there's text in them when clearly in your example, there isn't.

Comment: still waiting for any solutions.